# Python script with a sleep() statement does not log when run in background

Tags: python, bash, shell

I have a simple Python script I would like to run in the background, with the output redirected to a file e.g.

```
./test.py > output.log 2>&1 &
```

This works fine so long as there is no `sleep` statement in my Python script:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import sys
import time
from time import gmtime, strftime

urls=['http://a', 'http://b','http://c', 'http://d', 'http://e' ]

def main():
    while True:
        for url in urls:
            try:
                print url
            except Exception, e:
                print "Error checking url " + url
                print e
        #time.sleep(60)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If the sleep statement is uncommented then no output is generated when the script is run in the background.

If it is run in the foreground it works fine (with sleep) and the output is sent to console or file as I choose.

e.g. this always works:

```
./test.py > output.log
```

My question is, why does having the sleep statement prevent output from being directed to file when the script is run in the background, and how can I get round this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The output doesn't get lost, it simply takes a very long time to reach the file. This has to do with buffering: with the `sleep` it takes a long time for the output buffer to accumulate enough data to get flushed.

If you call `sys.stdout.flush()` just before calling `sleep()`, that'll make the output appear right away:

```
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(60)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried, but you could try using `sys.stdout.flush()` before sending your script to sleep.